# Unable to manipulate string

Tags: vb.net, httprequest, shoutcast

In my website i have a script that return the current song that playing from my shoutcast server in  a format of: **"artist-track"**, what i want to do is to take that string and split it to 
2 strings: artist and track, in order to do that i wrapped the script in server tag like  this:

```
<div id="nowPlaying" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://shoutcast.mixstream.net/js/song/uk3-free:34588"></script>     
</div>
```

and on code behind i did somthing like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

        Dim query() As String = nowPlaying.InnerText.Split("-")
        Dim artist As String = query(0)
        Dim track As String = query(1)
        Response.Write(artist + "<br />" + track)

    End Sub
```

the problem is that for some reason the string array is allways empty in fact i am unable to do any manipulation at all (remove, substring. lastIndexOf etc.)
it allways seems to be empty.

but if i dont do any manipulation on the string everything is ok and i can see the string like this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

        Dim query As String = nowPlaying.InnerText
        Response.Write(query)

 End Sub
```

any ideas why?

Comment: Can you post an example string ie the value of `nowPlaying.InnerText`?

Comment: this is the case in C# but in VB.NET the double quotes is for chars also, you can't do ('-') in vb.net.

Comment: you can see page source and example here: http://www.radioz.co.il/iframe/iframe2.aspx

Comment: `nowPlaying.InnerText` will not be returning the `artist - track` string as you are expecting. It will be returning the literal content of the DIV which is `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://shoutcast.mixstream.net/js/song/uk3-free:34588"></script>`. It is only when the page is rendered on the browser that this script tag is executed and the artist - track string is written to the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this...

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://shoutcast.mixstream.net/js/song/uk3-free:34588")
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())
Dim sTrim = reader.ReadToEnd()

reader.Close()
sTrim=sTrim.Replace("document.write('","")
sTrim=sTrim.SubString(0,sTrim.length-3)
Dim query() As String = sTrim.Split("-")
```

This loads the js file as a string and then removes the document.write syntax to leave you just artist-tile.

Comment: Be careful as characters such as apostrophe (`'`) may come out in HTML safe format ie `&#39;` etc etc. Just be aware to give it a good test. I would also have thought that there should be a more robust way of retrieving this information? But if it works it works! :) Thanks for the tick.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Dim query() As String = nowPlaying.InnerText.Split(New [Char]() {"-"c})
```

Comment: try: Dim query() As String = "This is-a test".Split(New [Char]() {"-"c})

Comment: with "This is-a test" its working, with nowPlaying.InnerText.Split still not working.

Comment: if i navigate to the script url this is what i see: document.write('artist - track'); - because i am not a javascript expert i can only take a guess that this is the problem...any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a stab but try:

```
Dim sTrim as String = nowPlaying.InnerText
sTrim=sTrim.Replace("document.write('","")
sTrim=sTrim.SubString(0,sTrim.length-3)
Dim query() As String = sTrim.Split("-")
```

Comment: not working...iv'e updated the page in the server with your code if you would like to see:http://www.radioz.co.il/iframe/iframe2.aspx

Comment: Can you insert a breakpoint on the second line of my code just after sTrim has been initialised and see what it is set to?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://shoutcast.mixstream.net/js/song/uk3-free:34588"></script>,  well i guess now we know why its not working because its not an actual string. my fault i should check it before i even posted the question.

Comment: :) Do you actually need the artist and track in the code-behind? Or is it just so you can show it on the page? If you just want it to appear on the page then I'd recommend doing the Split in Javascript after the page has rendered - that way you will be able to get the actual Artist - Title string that you need.

Comment: in need it because i am using it to query last.fm track.search that need this 2 parameters separately